# How to start an appfog locomotive.js app?

Tags: node.js, appfog, locomotivejs

I'm using the node framework locomotive.js on an appfog instance.  Installing this caused a slew of errors and I couldn't get the app to start.  Reviewing the help materials and working with appfog support we were able to resolve that the issue had to do with the package.json file and specifically the invocation of lcm server.

What is correct package.json property?

Comment: Unfortunately there is a conflict between the global install recommended in the quick start and the architecture of appfog.

package.json needs the following line to invoke lcm server as expected.

    "scripts": {
        "start": "node_modules/locomotive/bin/lcm server"
    },


If you've already got a global install it is also necessary to move /bin/lcm.js from your global node repo to the app's node_modules folder.  Otherwise, install locally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might check out https://github.com/hakaider/locomotive-appfog-sample

I just cloned it into my directory, ran npm install, then af update [my app name here] and it just worked.

Comment: I looked at the code and I can't tell you why that should be, but I'm not going to look a gift solution in the mouth.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that your answer is better than the answer I placed in comments as my answer in comments works, and explains why there's a problem, why my fix works... but since yours is easier to install, sure thing.

Comment: You make a fair point, sir, though I definitely appreciate the rep. =)